# Arrange/sort columns of dataframe for a stacked barplot

Tags: r, dataframe, plot, bar-chart

I am new to R. I wish to make a stacked barplot of a dataframe 'df' using `barplot(as.matrix(df))`. The problem is that I wish to arrange the columns of dataframe such that bars of the plot are in descending order of their length. The df is:

```
      A  B  C  D
val1  12 5  20 18
val2  20 15 28 7
```

[image: Stacked barplot]
.

I tried `reorder` function but that changed the width of bars, making some bars thinner and some thicker.

I want the bars to be in order-> C-A-D-B

```
df <- data.frame(
  A = c(12,20),
  B = c(5,15),
  C = c(20,28),
  D = c(18,7)
)

rownames(df) <- c("val1","val2")

barplot(as.matrix(df))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may order the data frame columns by it's negative `colSums` before plotting.

```
barplot(as.matrix(df[, order(-colSums(df))]))
```

***Yields***

[image]

***Data***

```
df <- structure(list(A = c(12, 20), B = c(5, 15), C = c(20, 28), D = c(18, 
7)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("val1", "val2"))
```

Answer (score 0):

A easy and mannualy way is just set the order of columns:

```
barplot(as.matrix(df[c("C","A","D","B")]))
```

Comment: Yes I know this, but not practical if there were many columns.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you may not want to sort based on row but you can easily sort by columns. Hopefully this is what you want

```
mt_trans <- t(matrix(c(12, 5, 20, 18, 20, 15, 28, 7), nrow = 2, byrow = TRUE))
newdata <- t(mt_trans[order(-mt_trans[,1]),])

barplot(newdata)
```